# Javascript if dynamic select element isnt NULL show other divs for that row in a table

Tags: javascript, select

I have a page with a table and each row has a dropdown `project_id`. Values are dynamically created from the database. I'm having trouble showing/hiding columns in that row.

If the value of the `project_id` dropdown is not 0 in a particular row I'd like to show columns `paid_by` and `reimbursement` else i'd like to hide the same to columns. This is what I have so far and I'm mostly focused on PHP in my project but Jquery is very helpful in some places and im trying to learn.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function() {
    //onload
    $('[class*="column_r_"]').hide(); //reimbursment column
    $('[class*="column_p_"]').hide(); //paid_by column

    //on project_id change (row specific)
$('select[name="project_id[]"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() != '') { //if val of THIS project_id is not NULL show comumns r & p in THAT row ONLY
            $('[class*="column_r_"]').show(); //reimbursment  column
            $('[class*="column_p_"]').show(); //paid_by column
        } else {  //else if val of THIS project_id is NULL hide comumns r & p in THAT row ONLY
            $('[class*="column_r_"]').hide(); //reimbursment column
            $('[class*="column_p_"]').hide(); //paid_by column
        } 
       });
    });
});
</script>
```

For simplicity the only HTML included here is what I've mentioned above

```
    <td> 
        <select class="form-control" id="project_id.$key" name="project_id[]">
                <option value="">
                    HINT: {{$expense->note}}
                </option>
                <option value="{{$project->id}}" 
                    {{ old('project_id', isset($expense->project_id) ? $expense->project_id : '') == $project->id ? "selected" : "" }}>
                    {{ $project->getProjectname() }}
                </option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control column_p_{{$expense->id}}" id="paid_by.$key" name="paid_by[]">
            <option value="0">
                {{ $primary_vendor->getName() }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control column_r_{{$expense->id}}" id="reimbursment.$key" name="reimbursment[]">
            <option value="0">None</option>
            <option value="Client">Client</option>
        </select>
    </td>
```

Every select object has a `.$key` at the end. So `id='project_id.1, .2, .3` and so on, so I'd like to think I can utilize this in my js code. I just need some guidance on how to target that.

Thanks!
Patryk
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: please provide html as well

Comment: You cannot hide or show a column slectively in some rows of a table. The column is either visible or not for all rows. I do not mean in JS only but generally with any table, HTML, Excel... What you can do is have the cell on that row display nothing, or even merge it with one of the nearby cells so that it takes over it's width.

Comment: Thanks Raul, the column would stay empty like in Picture 2 but the content inside that column inside each row would either show or hide. Sorry for not being specific.